# Configuring a VMDG280 router to point to an internal web server

Tags: router, webserver

I have a netgear VMDG280 router.  I have a static IP address.  Anyone know how I can configure this router so if I type in my IP address, it shows me the same apache ready webpage as I get when I go to localhost from the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Port forwarding is correct, as @Joe pointed out.  [Here](http://help.virginmedia.com/system/selfservice.controller?CMD=VIEW_ARTICLE&ARTICLE_ID=337901&CURRENT_CMD=SEARCH&CONFIGURATION=1002&PARTITION_ID=1&USERTYPE=1&LANGUAGE=en&COUNTY=us&VM_CUSTOMER_TYPE=Cable) is a link to a help page for your router model.  The section you are looking for is...

[image: PortForwarding]

- **Name:**  Whatever you want
- **Start Port:**  Probably 80, unless you want to have to append a `:1580` or something to the URL.
- **End Port:**  Whatever your Apache server is listening on... again, probably 80 unless you changed it.
- **Protocol:**  Both is fine
- **Local IP Address:**  IP of the machine your Apache server is running on.

Comment: I understand that you've said to use `Both` for the protocol option, but when would it be appropriate to use TCP or UDP?

Comment: It depends on the variety of data being transmitted.  Different higher level protocols are designed to use one, the other, or both.  TCP is used when reliability is the top concern, i.e., the receiver acknowledges receipt of every packet, and the sender waits for that acknowledgement before continuing.  UDP is used when speed is the top concern, i.e., no acknowledgments.  [Here](http://www.skullbox.net/tcpudp.php) is a nice explanation of the two in comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You need to forward the port on your router over to the machine with apache installed.
Not knowing the router myself I can only say you will need to direct traffic on port 80 hitting the router to point to the IP address you have assigned to your machine inside your subnet.
A really helpful guide, I find, is at http://portforward.com/help/portforwarding.htm